# Why wont Appgyver add all the necessary JS files?

Tags: model-view-controller, appgyver, supersonic

I'm developing an app using Supersonic & Appgyver. I generated two new modules[ `oAuth` & `default` ]and deleted "example" from a fresh default steroids applicaiton. I created a factory in the `oAuth` and I'm trying to call it in the `default` module.

Now! In auto generated `dist/app/default/login.html` ( the controller in question ) contains only the scripts

```
<script src="/app/common.js"></script>

<script src="/app/default.js"></script>
```

Why would it not load `/app/oAuth.js`?

My common index:

```
angular.module('common',
    'supersonic',
    'default',
    'oAuth'
]);
```

As far as I know, this should insist that oAuth should be included in all my other modules.

Why wont it auto add oAuth.js?

Comment: Can you post the initializer part of the other modules? For example: `angular.module('common',
    'supersonic',
    'default',
    'oAuth'
])` without the controller part?

Comment: I've since started adding anything I need to be "common" in the common module. I ended up assuming that's what supersonic wants me to do. In the other modules I tried using ONLY 'common' and add all other modules with no dice. I can rewrite what I was doing and post if my new common logic isn't true.

Comment: I was just curious about how the modules are instantiated. If they are instantiated with no parameters (not even an empty array) there can be issues with Angular. For example, `angular.module('default').controller(...` could cause issues if you don't add the `[]` parameter to module. It would look like this after: `angular.module('default', []).controller(...`. I am not sure it solves the issue, but I have experienced it many times with this platform and Angular.

Comment: Oh of course, I learned that one early on!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Supersonic is supposed to add those files. I believe it wants everything "common" to be in the common module. You could of course manually add the files to /dist but that's a pain.